# How to count callbacks?

Tags: node.js, asynccallback

I tried collect data from 3 sources but these are async. Therefore i tried to count callback. This is code which i wrote for this purpose.

```
var http = require('http');
var data_str1 = '';
var data_str2 = '';
var data_str3 = '';
var ended = 0;
function callback1(response){
    response.on('end', function(){ended++;});
    response.on('data', function(data){
        data_str1 += data;
    });
}

function callback2(response){
    response.on('end', function(){ended++;});
    response.on('data', function(data){
        data_str2 += data;
    });
}

function callback3(response){
    response.on('end', function(){ended++;});
    response.on('data', function(data){
        data_str3 += data;
    });
}

http.get(process.argv[2], function(response){
    callback1(response);
    if (ended == 3) console.log(data_str1);
});

http.get(process.argv[3], function(response){
    callback2(response);
    if (ended == 3) console.log(data_str2);
});

http.get(process.argv[4], function(response){
    callback3(response);
    if (ended == 3) console.log(data_str3);
});
```

Can you tell me what is the problem in this code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you use the async library or promises?

Comment: @Andrius I am new to nodejs and i am trying to solve learnyounode's question. Question want solving without any library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my solution. I've tested and it works.

```
var http = require('http');
var concat = require('concat-stream');

var urls = [];
var responses = [];
var count = 0;

for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
  urls.push(process.argv[i]);
}

function readResponse(index) {
  http.get(urls[index], function(response) {
    response.pipe(concat(function(data) {
      responses[index] = data.toString();
      count++;

      if (count == 3) {
        responses.forEach(function(response) {console.log(response);});
      }
    }));
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  readResponse(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const http = require('http');
const bl = require('bl');
const results = [];
let count = 0;
function printResults () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(results[i])
  }
}

function httpGet (index) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
      }

      results[index] = data.toString()
      count++

      if (count === 3) {
        printResults()
      }
    }))
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  httpGet(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems here is 
`if (ended == 3) console.log(data_str2);`
will run after `callback2(response);`
It not wait for  `response.on('end', function(){ended++;});`

Answer (score 0):

My solution, simple and straight to the point

```
const http = require('http')
const bl = require('bl')
const results = []
let count = 0

function printResults () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(results[i])
  }
}

function httpGet (index) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
      }

      results[index] = data.toString()
      count++

      if (count === 3) {
        printResults()
      }
    }))
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  httpGet(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code check the ended value (ended===3) within the callback functions. I solved the problem using a similar approach.Note that I have used one callback function for all three urls

```
const http = require("http");

let url1 = process.argv[2];
let url2 = process.argv[3];
let url3 = process.argv[4];
let str1 = "";
let str2 = "";
let str3 = "";
let end = 0;

function cb(response, str) {
  response.on("data", data => {
    if (str === "str1") str1 += data;
    if (str === "str2") str2 += data;
    if (str === "str3") str3 += data;
  });
  response.on("end", () => {
    end++;
    if (end === 3) {
      console.log(`${str1}\n${str2}\n${str3}`);
    }
  });
}

http.get(url1, response => {
  cb(response, "str1");
});

http.get(url2, response => {
  cb(response, "str2");
});

http.get(url3, response => {
  cb(response, "str3");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

My working solution with less code:

```
const http = require('http')

const [, , URL_1, URL_2, URL_3] = process.argv

const printData = (URL, cb) =>
    () => http.get(URL, res => {
        let data = ''
        res.on('data', chunk => data += chunk.toString())
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log(data)
            cb()
        })
    })

printData(URL_1, printData(URL_2, printData(URL_3, null)))()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I will leave my comment for people who might read this nowadays. From Node.js perspective your answers is not so good. The cause is that you don't use async power here. You just call to all 3 URLs one after one but only when the earlier will read all data from GET. And it is not what OP asked about. He asked for "how to count callbacks" which is used to work the async way with Node.js.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question, but I just wanted to share my ugly-ass solution with a different approach.

```
const http = require('http');

let data1 = '';
let data2 = '';
let data3 = '';

http.get(process.argv[2], (res) => {
    res.on('data', (data) => {
        data1 += data;
    })
    res.on('end', () => {
        http.get(process.argv[3], (res) => {
            res.on('data', (data) => {
                data2 += data;
            })
            res.on('end', () => {
                http.get(process.argv[4], (res) => {
                    res.on('data', (data) => {
                        data3 += data;
                    })
                    res.on('end', () => {
                        console.log(data1); console.log(data2); console.log(data3);
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```